# Including "Best in show" type award for a conference paper on CV

Tags: publications, conference, cv, awards

I work in industry, but come from an academic background. We publish several papers a year in journals and conference proceedings. I'm also preparing a new CV for academic purposes. Earlier this year, a paper that I coauthored was selected for the "best paper in [technical category]" award they give at the end.

If a conference paper that you have coauthored receives this kind of "best in whatever" type award at the conference it was presented at, is it appropriate to include a mention of that on a CV? If so, how? This is geared toward proper academia, not a resume.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7895/awards-when-applying-for-faculty-jobs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's common to have an "Awards" section on an academic CV; you could put it there.  Give the exact name of the award, identify the group that awarded it, briefly explain what the award was for, and list the date.

See also [How much detail to include for an award listed on a CV](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10692/how-much-detail-to-include-for-an-award-listed-on-a-cv?rq=1).